# Auto-implement abstract methods in Java with Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, refactoring, tooling

I have an abstract class which is being extended by 100 classes. I add another abstract method to the abstract class. How can I implement a stub method into all subclasses at once?

Comment: If you don't actually want to provide real implementations in every class, maybe just make it virtual instead of abstract? (You could always take the time to override it with a real implementation in every class and *then* make it abstract.)

Comment: Maybe make the method non-abstract with basic no-op implementation and override only where necessary?